# Self destruction

Tags: selfdestruct

I am also newer to solidity. It appears there is a self destruction option for solidity.
If I use that, it seems I also would be eligible to receive some gas as a refund for freeing up space in the blockchain.
Can anyone explain me how this has refund actually works?